# getting text of particular control on rowcommand event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to take text of linkbutton in rowcommand event.

I am clicking on the linkbutton and according to text bound to it, i want to do futher logic.

On rowdatabound i have binded text to link button depending upon certain values in database.

Now on rowcommand, i want to check if text of that linkbutton is "Make as Active" then further logic and else further logic.

I tried to make it as:

```
Protected Sub GrdMovieLst_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GrdMovieLst.RowCommand
            If e.CommandName = "ActiveCheck" Then
                Dim gvRow As GridViewRow = GrdMovieLst.Rows(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument))
                if gvRow.FindControl("lbActiveCheck").Text Then /*here text property is not comming
            End If
End Sub
```

NOTE: Code help in C# is also fine with me.

gvRow.FindControl("lbActiveCheck").Text is not giving me text of linkbutton. I want to get the text of link button of that particular row.

Please help me.

ASPX for link button:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                                                    Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
 | <asp:LinkButton ID="lbActiveCheck" runat="server"   CommandName="ActiveCheck"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Help in c# is also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this:

```
 Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, Control).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)

CType(row.FindControl("lbActiveCheck"), LinkButton).Text = "Make As Inactive"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit"
                                                    Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
 | <asp:LinkButton ID="lbActiveCheck" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'  CommandName="ActiveCheck"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```